# Работа с формами в PascalABC.NET: Переход с одной формы на другую

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Никак не заставлю при нажатии кнопки перейти с одной формы на другую(Кнопка стоит на Form1 в Unit1. Перейти надо на Form2 в Unit2).
Кнопку описал так:

```
procedure Form1.button3_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
var Form2:Form;    
begin   
Form2.show;
end;
```

В Unit1 подключил Unit2

```
uses System, Unit2, System.Drawing и т.д
```

Пишет:Ошибка времени выполнения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

P.S
При создании в дизайнере форм кроме Unit'a создается сам файл Project'a. Там я добавил:

```
uses Unit1,Unit2;
```

Запускает вторую форму :D Но не при нажатии кнопки а сразу, проигнорировав первую форму(то есть при нажатии "Выполнить" сразу запускает Form2.

Ребят, подскажите что я делаю не так

Comment: Form2 (в вашем случае) неинициализированная переменная, поэтому и возникает ошибка

Comment: @nuts119 всмысле неинициализированная?
Вроде все ввел. Может я не понимаю...
Где она должна быть инициализированна?

Comment: Вот здесь Вы объявили переменную, но не инициализировали ее.

var Form2:Form;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите строчку `var Form2:Form;`

```
procedure Form1.button3_Click(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);
begin   
  Form2.show;
end;
```

Если Вы добавили в `Uses` `Unit2`, в котором объявлена глобальная переменная `Form2`, то этого достаточно. Глобальная `Form2` должна быть проинициализирована. А вот локальная переменная (которую вы объявили в методе `button3_Click` и к которой обращаетесь в Вашем коде) не проинициализирована. Т.е. там нет объекта, его туда еще никто не положил.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci То есть я все правильно сделал,  просто надо удалить обьявленную переменную?

Comment: @Sin2p, да. А то происходило затенение переменной.

Comment: @nuts119 спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: @Sin2p, да, все было верно, кроме лишней переменной.